# Replacing a line of code in html

Tags: javascript, html, replace, line

Is it possible to use javascript to take this code for example:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="the function I need to use">
</form>
```

and change line #2 to this on the onclick event in line 3 with javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="text" style="width: 25px;">
```

So basically, I need to know if I can use javascript to replace a certain line of code with a completely different line of code, so that I can do things like make images that change when I click on them, and change back when I click on them again. Please try to explain your answer. I only understand html by asking questions and finding what I need when I need it. I do not actually KNOW html. If you can answer my question, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Answer: Yes. Now go to a javascript/html tutorial online, they're free

Comment: Please understand: when you do as directed in any of the answers here, you are not actually "replacing" code. You are modifying the attributes of existing nodes in the DOM, or possibly adding/removing nodes. As suggested, you really ought to seek out a tutorial to gain a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can.  Use 'setAttribute' or 'getAttribute' property for setting and retrieving values.

```
var inputText=document.getElementById('text');
inputText.setAttribute('style','width:25px');

OR

inputText.style.width='25px';
```

**Updated Code:-**

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="the function I need to use">
</form>

<script>
var inputText=document.getElementById('text');
    inputText.setAttribute('style','width:25px');
</script>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to put this in to my current code. As I said, I know very little about all this. @RashFlash

Comment: i have updated my answer with code, check that. regards.

Answer (score 1):

To set the width of the attribute.. Please Do this...

```
document.getElementById('text').setAttribute('style','width:25px');
```

if u want to remove it then at that tiem u can use

```
document.getElementById('text').removeAttribute('style','width:25px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('text').style.width="25px";
```

The above should work.

It takes the element by its ID `text` and applies the style of `"width=25px"` to it.

Demo:<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/s24ZW/</kbd>

Comment: use `document.getElementById('idOfImage').src="url of image";`